# Standard References for 5d or 6d SUSY theories?

Tags: resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, spacetime-dimensions

I'd like to learn more about them, but I need a text that I know is worth reading to start!

Comment: Are you mostly interested in (0,2) theory and its N=1 5d limit?